# Magento 2: sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure: Invalid state change requested

Tags: magento2, sessions

I cannot get my head around this, I cannot replicate it, it's driving me nuts.

About 1% of orders encounter this error. It was even worse before, but now I've changed the default behaviour of sending the order confirmation emails and it's better, but the error still persists.

I've placed a logger on the sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure event, and this is what I've found so far:

The error (& trace):

```
Invalid state change requested Error trace: #0 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Plugin\AccessChangeQuoteControl->beforeSave(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #1 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #2 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array) #3 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(522): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #4 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(406): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Array) #5 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(364): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #6 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartManagement.php(87): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder('12072', NULL) #7 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(106): Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement->placeOrder('6cO0iqVSBtALdCO...') #8 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('6cO0iqVSBtALdCO...', 'gilea_irina@yah...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) #9 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array) #10 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('6cO0iqVSBtALdCO...', 'gilea_irina@yah...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) #11 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array) #12 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('6cO0iqVSBtALdCO...', 'gilea_irina@yah...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) #13 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #14 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(244): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy)) #15 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #16 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #17 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #18 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #19 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #20 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #21 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() #22 /public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #23 {main}
```

And more, during that event:
- customer is not seen as a guest (customer_is_guest on order model & quote model returns 0)
- customer ID exists on both quote & order model. Sometimes, customer ID matches an account that has the same email. Sometimes, it's a very close match (maybe the same customer that has a customer account using other email address?)
- all orders end up, eventually, created with customer_is_guest = 1;

I suspect a session problem, seems the most likely scenario. I'm using cart persistency as well, guest orders are enabled, multishipping is not. Magento 2.2.6 on litespeed (no litemage) & redis for file & session storage (the problem occurs without redis as well).

Please don't tell me to look where the error is thrown, already mentioned I can't replicate it.

Comment: Are you using ParadoxLab Auth.net module?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155585)

Answer (score 0):

The error should be coming from this file: paradoxlabs/authnetcim/Observer/CheckoutFailureClearAcceptjsObserver.php
$this->quoteRepository->save($payment->getQuote()); is throwing the invalid state error.
After the error has been threw, the customer can resend the request which creates an invalid order. The reason of the error is not replicable for now.

You can fix this by adding an error check before customer placing an order, so they won't be able to checkout with an invalid quote.
Add a plugin to add a check **"! $this->changeQuoteControl->isAllowed($quote)"** class QuoteManagement beforePlaceOrder to make sure the quote is valid.

Here is a link from Magento github who also has the same issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9051
You can see this is related to ParadoxLabs

If you want to debug this issue, you will need to patch Magento with this patch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22037